# Empty message Hash length

Tags: hash

I am learning Hash Algorithms and in a [presentation (PDF)](http://discovery.csc.ncsu.edu/Courses/csc574-F09/slides/T04_HashFunctions.6pp.pdf) about these algorithms I read that:

> Length of $h(m)$ much shorter then length of $m$.

Now my question is:
What if we talk about an empty string, is it true that hash length is shorter than the length of message?

I searched the internet and  found that:

> The MD5 Hash of an empty string is:`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The presentation probably went along with a more verbose lecture.

I would assume there was some discussion about message lengths there, since that statement is obviously incorrect. In *most* applications, the "message" length is longer than the digest, and the average message length is also most likely longer. Think file verification, or processing of an actually message, instead of of a password.

In that statement, substitute "much shorter" to "usually much shorter"